# Shorten form field width bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap, text inputs are naturally 100% width of page.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                     {{ Form::label('name', 'Name *') }}
                     {{ Form::text('name', Input::old('name'), array('class' => 'form-control’)) }}
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                     {{ Form::label('desc', 'Description') }}
                     {{ Form::text('desc', Input::old('desc'), array('class' => 'form-control’)) }}
              </div>
         </div><!-- div.col-md-12 end -->
     </div><!-- div.row-fluid body end -->
</div><!-- div.container-fluid end -->
```

What is the proper, Bootstrap way to have form fields be shorter?

Answer (score 1):

wrap them in column classes

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-3">Field</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works.  I used it.  I wonder if there is a conciser/elegenter way of doing this common requirement.

Comment: Maybe. What i do to feel better about it is push my error messages into the empty div. once they have a purpose, its feels like a much better solution :).

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do declare a `<div class="col-md-12">`. If you wanna put your two form-groups right next to each other try something like this.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                 {{ Form::label('name', 'Name *') }}
                 {{ Form::text('name', Input::old('name'), array('class' => 'form-control’)) }}
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                 {{ Form::label('desc', 'Description') }}
                 {{ Form::text('desc', Input::old('desc'), array('class' => 'form-control’)) }}
          </div>
 </div><!-- div.row body end -->
```

If you want to put three form groups next to each other you can put `col-md-4` next to each `form-group` and so on. Let me know if this helped.

Comment: I know that you can have multiple columns in a row and put form fields in each one, but this is not what I want.